# Timescaledata within Microsoft project using VBA to pull Resource Usage Data

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am just beginning a new project for my internship within the Project Management Office and they wanted me to look at some VBA within a script they run weekly to update each project on their Sharepoint server.

We are trying to get to the timephase data that shows up on resource usage view. We would ideally like to pull the right side of the screen that displays the total hours for each resource spread out over Mon - Friday.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if more detail here would help.

Jacob

Comment: Take a look at [TimeScaleData in Project using .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61029833/timescaledata-in-project-using-net). You'll want to loop through Resources instead of Tasks and modify for vba, but otherwise the code is the same.

Comment: I will do just that! Thank you for your help, it is much appreciated.