# How to work with MS Project TimeScaleValue object using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, win32com, ms-project

I'm trying to create a graph with data from an MPP file using win32com.client to read the data. But after consulting [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/project/concepts/resources-object-map-project), I tried to start with a simple code.

```
import win32com.client

mppFileName = 'C:/python/test.mpp'

mpp = win32com.client.Dispatch("MSProject.Application")
mpp.visible = 0
    
mpp.FileOpen(mppFileName)
project = mpp.ActiveProject

ResourceList = project.Resources
assignments = project.Assignments
    
for resource in ResourceList:
    if resource.Work != 0:
        print(resource.Name, ' ', resource.Job)
     
mpp.FileClose(Save=0)
  
exit()
```

But this code generates an error on the `assignments=` line (`Assignments` is 'unknown'). Does anyone know the correct way to work with Assignments and TimeScaleValues ​​objects? My goal is to create a graph with the amount of work assigned by week to each project resource.

Comment: `project` doesn't have an `Assignments` property, but `resource` does, as per the documentation link you provide.

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment! Using the documentation I understood that I have two nested collections that I have to declare. I already tried to use 
"Assigments = ResourceList.Assigments", "Assignments = Resources.Assignment", and other variances, but nothing seems to work. This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.assignment) VBA documentation does not helped me a lot too...

Comment: Have you tried `assignments = resource.Assignments` in the 'for' loop? The documentation is very clear: Assignments is a property of the Resource object (like `Work`): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.resource.assignments

Comment: Thank you for your help!  With your comments and Rachel's answers, I was able to go ahead. I have to do the assignments inside loop and not outside... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to loop through the [Assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.assignments) collection for each [Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.resource). Then for each [Assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.assignment), loop through the time periods you want (e.g. weeks) using the [TimeScaleData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.resource.timescaledata) method which is the key to reading (and setting) work by day/week/etc. This method returns a [TimeScaleValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.timescalevalues) collection of [TimeScaleValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.timescalevalue) objects.

pseudo code:

```
for r in ResourceList:
  asgmts = r.Assignments
  for a in asgmts 
    ''' create timescalevalues collection to loop through time periods'''
    tsvs = a.TimeScaleData(start, end, type, unit)
    for tsv in tsvs
      ' aggregate the work as needed
```

Other useful objects to know: [Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/project/concepts/application-and-projects-object-map-project), [Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/project/concepts/tasks-object-map-project) collection, [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task) object, and [Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/project/concepts/resources-object-map-project) collection

Also search stackoverflow for [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms-project%5Dtimescaledata) such as [TimeScaleData in Project using .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61029833/timescaledata-in-project-using-net). Most questions & answers will not be python (c#, vb.net, vba) but the core of using the project object model will be applicable.

Comment: What are the possible values for type and unit?

Comment: @CamiloMartinezM. the link to the documentation is in the answer. Click on TimeScaleData.